# When should one use \verb and when \texttt

Tags: verbatim, syntax, typewriter

Sometimes people here use `\verb!A SHORT COMMAND!` and sometimes `\textt{A SHORT COMMAND}`.
I'm unsure when to use which.

Are there any guidelines or arguments for `\verbatim` vs. `\texttt`?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The short answer is you use `\verb` where you need to write a small piece of inline verbatim material that contains characters TeX treats (or rather, is currently treating) as special. `\texttt` is for when you just want typewriter font.

`\verb` has some downsides, such as not working in moving arguments. In those cases, you're probably better off using `\texttt` (or related semantic markup) and performing the appropriate escaping.

Comment: I'd recommend using `\texttt` (or, better, a macro with semantic name that uses `\texttt`) unless you know it won't work for your particular string, such as with `\verb|x=1%2|`. And even then, using `\texttt{1\%2}` is probably just as good.

Comment: Another huge downside of `\verb` I think is it sometimes doesn't work with other environments. I think for instance you can't use `\verb` in a `\section{}` environment.

Comment: Would using `\protect` allow `\verb` to work in moving arguments? I'm only asking, because I don't know how to test for myself.

Comment: @TylerCrompton: No.

Comment: A disadvantage of \texttt{} is that you don't get vertical single quotes, even with `\usepackage{upquote}`.  I want those if I'm using tt to represent source code/computer input (which is about the only thing I use tt for).

Comment: A related disadvantage of `\texttt` is that it [doubles the space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118455) after the colon. No idea how to avoid this one. (Incidentally, it shows that `\texttt` may silently “mess up” with characters without saying anything and possibly without the author’s knowledge, which I find scary – I wonder what the complete list is of such characters that have to be watched for when using `\texttt`.)

Answer (score 41):

Sometimes using `\verb|...|` is better. For example if you copy paste a piece of code like `__start:` in a `\texttt{}` environment you might get an error as symbol "`_`" is not inside a math environment. And then you have to rewrite the code like this: "`\texttt{\_\_start}`". But why would you do this when you can just use:"`\verb|__start|`".

Comment: Notice that `\verb{__start}` will give tons of errors. I've fixed the delimiters: they should be identical characters that are not among those to typeset verbatim.

Answer (score 19):

One advantage of `\verb` is that underscores are typeset better. For example in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\texttt{foo\_bar}

\verb|foo_bar|
\end{document}
```

the first `foo_bar` has a thinner underscore. See [Underscores in words (text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

`\texttt` allows line breaks, whereas `\verb` does not. They serve slightly different purposes.

Comment: …also in the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Just found that wanting to highlight text in a document makes a difference....

highlighting with

```
\usepackage{color,soul}
```

and

```
\hl{text to highlight}
```

This works fine if the text to highlight includes `\texttt` but fails with `\verb`

so for example

```
\hl{\texttt{printf} format specifiers}
```

works fine, but

```
\hl{\verb$printf$ format specifiers}
```

fails...

Comment: The problem isn't with `\hl`, but with `\verb`. `\verb` (and any other verbatim-like commands and environments) don't work in arguments to other commands. It's the same principle as here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447081/134574

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, thanks for the helpful comment and for checking out this very very very late answer

Answer (score 1):

One more thing: `\texttt{  Hello  }` will print `Hello`, while `\verb|  Hello  |` will print  `Hello` . In other words, `\texttt` ignores leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to what @TH mentioned, `\texttt` also works well inside `equation`/`eqnarray` environments and TikZ code. `\verb` (in its primitive form) doesn't work very well in such cases.

Comment: `\verb` (in its primitive form) works without problem in `equation` (or `eqnarray`)...