# Combination of \verb and \texttt

Tags: verbatim, macros

Also I read: [When should one use \verb and when \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/when-should-one-use-verb-and-when-texttt)

My issue at hand is that I would like to write a little more than just "small pieces" (wording in linked question) of program code, but without having to escape all the special characters. On the other hand, `\verb` does not have `{}`-style delimiters, besides being said to have issues with moving arguments.

Is there something I can do such that (sample text follows)

"As a user, do `\texttt{if (!(last\_cond \&\& (last\_flags \& (O\_CREATE | O\_EXCL))))}`, but as root, do `\texttt{if (!(last\_cond \&\& (last\_flags \& (O\_RDONLY))))}` until..."

can be written as

"As a user, do `\texttt{if (!(last_cond && (last_flags & (O_CREATE | O_EXCL))))}`, but as root, do `\texttt{if (!(last_cond && (last_flags & (O_RDONLY))))}` until..."

edit: 
Defining a new command as in `\verbdef` and having to write "As a user, do `\verbdef\demo1{\texttt{if (!(last_cond && (last_flags & (O_CREATE | O_EXCL))))}}\demo1`, but as root, do `\verbdef\demo2{\texttt{if (!(last_cond && (last_flags & (O_RDONLY))))}}\demo2` until..." does read strangely (in the tex source file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small}
\begin{document}
foo
\lstinline{if (!(last_cond && (last_flags & (O_CREATE | O_EXCL))))}
bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: `backgroundcolor` cannot be set for inline, right?

Comment: @xport: right, no background colors and frames

Answer (score 2):

Use the [verbdef](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verbdef/) package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbdef}
\begin{document}
\verbdef\demo{if (!(last_cond && (last_flags & (O_CREATE | O_EXCL))))}
\demo
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does seem strange to define a new macro for every new string that one wants to be output.

Comment: @user2859 Use the `listings` package for large blocks of code! What is it exactly you are after? Your question is not very clear.