# In-line \verb -- overfull hbox problem

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

I'm having a problem that I've had before and I'm tired of hacking my way through it and hope that there is some supported solution.  I'll go ahead and create a document for example:

```
\documentclass {article}
\begin{document}
\section {Introduction}
In the introduction of the document, you will find plenty of verbatim \verb|texts
that| have an hard time wrapping.
\end{document}
```

So, the problem here is that the `\verb` environment doesn't wrap well (unlike the example I posted above where I put in the return to aid in viewing).  There is an overfull hbox error.

How can I make the `\verb` command wrap and justify with its surroundings better?  I would expect LaTeX to just increase or decrease the spacing around the `\verb` command.  Is it just too much smooshing or stretching for LaTeX to agree to do it?  Thanks in advance for any help.

[EDIT]
After reading [When should one use \verb and when \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/when-should-one-use-verb-and-when-texttt) I think that `\texttt` may be the right way to go here.  This considerably covers the question above, but the question still stands: What about `\verb`?

[EDIT] Also see the related question about `\texttt{}` [\texttt overfull hbox problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10377/texttt-overfull-hbox-problem)

Comment: I is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your name below it) or to have any formal greeting. Also, there are plenty of female TeX users!

Comment: @Caramdir, thanks for the correction!  No need to go into it, but "Sirs" doesn't limit the address to male users: it's generic.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `\verb` macro is for *verbatim* text, i.e. to tell LaTeX to interpret the characters without their special meaning. It is only intended to be used for short inline verbatim material, like explaining a LaTeX macro. 
For longer verbatim material there is the `verbatim` environment (and several others). The fact that it is printed in tt font is just a side-effect!
If you use spaces inside verbatim text you are *requesting* a verbatim, unstretchable and unbreakable space. The star-version `\verb*` even prints these spaces using a visual symbol.

**Please always use `\texttt` or `\ttfamily`** for text which should be printed in `tt` font.
The use of `\verb` simply for the font is a misuse. You can use it for short words without penalty, but for longer text this issues arise. Note that verbatim mode is fragile and `\verb` doesn't work inside macro arguments.

If you *really* want to use it try the `shortvrb`package which allows you to use one character for verbatim text, e.g. only `|text|` instead of  `\verb|text|`. Then you can exclude the spaces like that:

```
... verbatim |texts| |that| have ...
```

One common use of this is in package documentation, where `|` is already a short verbatim marker. It allows package authors to print macros they describe verbatim or some shorter related text in `tt` font. Again: it is not intended to be used for longer text.

---

**Edit:**

- N.B. for `|` to work as a delimiter in the `shortverb` package, you have to 
  define it using the command `\MakeShortVerb{\|}`

Documentation for the `shortverb` package is available [here](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/doc.pdf).

Comment: So you've answered most of the question, but still one remains, does LaTeX justify AROUND the `\verb` command to offset badness of hboxes?  Am I experiencing a limit of the spacing squishiness that LaTeX does, or is LaTeX being on purpose stupid (or verbatim) in this case?  Thanks for your answer, very helpful!

Comment: Let me add that it would be possible to define a `\verb` like macro which keeps the spaces as normal spaces, which would allow for line breaks. But IMHO there is no reason to do so.

Comment: LaTeX will stretch or shrink the other spaces in the same line in order to compensate for a longer verb box, but this has its limits. If you have longer verb text on a line not much room is left for other text with spaces for the correct shrink.