# \texttt overfull hbox problem

Tags: line-breaking, typewriter

I asked a question earlier about `\verb` and overfull hbox :
[In-line \verb -- overfull hbox problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10372/in-line-verb-overfull-hbox-problem/10373#10373)

And regarding the solution there, changed many of my `\verb`s to `\texttt{}`s.  I have come up with a new problem now.  An example:

```
\documentclass {article}
\begin{document}
\section {Introduction}

    The entry point is in \texttt{TRCS.Main()} (\texttt{TRCS\char`\\TRCS.cs}). 
  The stateless (see \S 3.4.3) forms are started immediately, then another controller
  is invoked, namely  \texttt{Workflow}.
\end{document}
```

Compiling this example will show my problem.  `\texttt{Workflow}` causes an overflow, and a rather significant one.  What should I do to alleviate the problem?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Informally speaking, TeX break lines at spaces (and a few other positions in a word, called "discretionary break"). Discretionary break is not allowed in typewriter typesetting. If there is no space in `\texttt{}`, it cannot break.

For your example, there is no help using `\texttt` instead of `\verb`. There are several ways to solve such kind of problem:

1. Enable microtype for pdfTeX (suggested):

   ```
   \usepackage{microtype}
   ```
2. Enable hythenation of TT text:

   ```
   \usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
   ```
3. Use a sloppy paragraph:

   ```
   \sloppy
   ```

   or

   ```
   \begin{sloppypar}
   The entry point is...
   \end{sloppypar}
   ```

   This may cause bad spacing.
4. Enable break manually:

   ```
   \texttt{Work\allowbreak flow}
   ```

   This is not useful here, but may be useful for `\texttt{TRCS.\allowbreak Main()}`

Comment: The tip of `\allowbreak` was helpful for me.  When writing method names in code, I would suggest against using hyphenation and toward `\allowbreak`.  I'm making a habit of inserting these at the case changes in in my camel-case method names.

Comment: But I still don't get a "-" in the end of the line, indicating that next lines word is part of previous line! Otherwise nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the packages `url` and `path`.
Both have pros and cons, depending on what you want.
So far, I used `path` and am pleased with it.

Note that the command `\path{}` exists even without loading the path package.
From what I saw, its behaviour is more or less the same, but you cannot specify the break characters.

Finally, in addition to `\allowbreak` already mentioned, you can also use `\-` to define conditional breaks. But in that case, LaTeX will put a dash at the end of the line.

Comment: To my surprise, \path does not support unicode characters.