# How to get my teletype (\tt) text to wrap to the next line, rather than run off the edge of the PDF?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, typewriter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\texttt overfull hbox problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10377/texttt-overfull-hbox-problem)
>   [How to automatically hyphenate within \texttt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt)

Much of the LaTeX documents I write deal with computer-sciencey stuff that I like to put in monospace using either `\tt` or `\texttt`, but if the pieces of text that I wrap in teletype are toward the end of a line in the pdf, instead of breaking to the next line, they continue off the edge of the PDF. Is there a way to get this to break to the next line?

A similar [question to this regarding underlined text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/why-does-underlined-text-not-get-wrapped-once-it-hits-the-end-of-a-line) uses an extra package to do this. Is there a way for me to do this with the existing `\tt` command or is there some extra package that I will have to use?

**Edit** - Here is an example of the problem:

```
Here is a bunch of text explaining all the intimate details of the oh so very
important research that I do. At about this point in my description, I would
like to reference the qualified name of an important method that I will then
go into a great amount of detail about,
so here it is {\tt fantasticPackageName.LongAndFancyClassName.importantMethodName()}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add an example of the problem?

Comment: @egreg I have added an example of the problem I am experiencing.

Comment: You can find a solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt