# Can't get teletype \texttt to move to next line

Tags: line-breaking, typewriter

I'm having a problem that, whenever I have a lengthy region of `\texttt{}` at the end of a line where it continues to trail off rather than wrapping to the next line.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
\texttt{commodo.ligula.eget} dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque 
penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, 
aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. 

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered example]

Other users have asked how to wrap the text within the `texttt`, however, I'm interested in moving the entire `texttt` to the next line (since none of my regions are long enough that they should need to be broken up). To be clear: I want all of each `texttt` to be on a single line.

This is NOT a duplicate of [this SO question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82644/how-to-get-my-teletype-tt-text-to-wrap-to-the-next-line-rather-than-run-off), in which the OP wanted to solve this problem by breaking the text inside the teletype region.

Comment: Using an empty line and `\noindent\textt{...}` after *Aenean* does not help? But I would use another command for this, which does this for you

Comment: Should the line before the `\texttt` be filled up or just broken at the point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want that the line which can't contain the text in typewriter font be broken at the spot, here's a variation of the `\filbreak` macro in the TeXbook (page 111):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\wtt[1]{%
  \hfil\penalty0\hfilneg\texttt{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
\wtt{commodo.ligula.eget} dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
penatibus et magnis \wtt{dis.parturient.montes}, nascetur ridiculus mus.
Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel,
aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the break is taken at the penalty, the `\hfilneg` will disappear at the line break; otherwise it will cancel the `\hfil`.

However, in the case you have many unbreakable long chunks of text, `\raggedright` typesetting should be considered.

Comment: Wow, I've been looking for this from my beginning with TeX. I always preferred that rather than an overfull box.

Comment: This works great! I'll be using this from now on, though I think I'm going to override the `texttt` function, rather than creating my own, so I don't have to replace them all in the document.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion here would be to allow your paragraphs to be a little `\sloppy`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
\texttt{commodo.ligula.eget} dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque 
penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, 
aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. 

\sloppy
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
\texttt{commodo.ligula.eget} dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque 
penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, 
aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. 

\end{document}
```

From [`source2e`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **63 Page styles and related commands**):

> `\sloppy` will never (well, hardly ever) produce overfull boxes, but may produce [underfull](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138/5764) ones.

If you wish the `\sloppy` to be isolated or localized, issue it as part of the `sloppypar` environment:

```
\begin{sloppypar}
<sloppy paragraph(s)>
\end{sloppypar}
```

Comment: I've preferred @egreg's answer because it's much cleaner, but this is no less correct. Thanks!

Comment: @GJStein: I'd almost suggest using a `\raggedright` formatting for your paragraphs.

Comment: This is for my thesis, for which the formatting is largely not up to me, which is why I've tried to keep side-effects to a minimum.