# line-breaking across all document/objects automatically?

Tags: line-breaking

I find myself manually fixing long variable names between `$$` and `\texttt{}` and other objects (there are plenty of those in my document since .

Those fixes don't hold well after text changes, and sometimes require finding specific workarounds for each object.

Is there a way to force text wrapping across all objects of a document in a generic way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299/how-to-get-long-texttt-sections-to-break and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10377/texttt-overfull-hbox-problem and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67440/break-an-inline-math-formula and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/allowing-line-break-at-in-inline-math-mode. There is not a really generic way. You should put such things in display math which makes it much easier to read.

Comment: probably you should use one of the url package commands such as `\path` rather than `\texttt` as these allow highly customisable line breaking at specific characters. But hard to say without any example