# Why is there extra space after (:) in \texttt{}

Tags: spacing

Whenever I type a space after a colon (:) in a `\texttt{}` command I end up with extra space — here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\section*{Test Space after Colon}  

\texttt{1234 : 8901}\\
\texttt{12345678901}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\noindent 
The above was produced by 
\begin{verbatim}
\texttt{1234 : 8901}\\
\texttt{12345678901}  
\end{verbatim}
and has extra space after 
the colon (:) 

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\noindent 
\textsf{1234 : 8901}\\
\textsf{12345678901}

\noindent 
The above was produced by 
\begin{verbatim}
\textsf{1234 : 8901}\\
\textsf{12345678901}  
\end{verbatim}
and has no extra space after 
the colon (:) 

\end{document}
```

The above code produces

[image: Test space after colon]

As you can see in the example, the extra space does not appear in the `\textsf{}` command for example.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: It seems to come from the punctuation feature just as with `.`, try adding `\frenchspacing` in the preamble. Unsure why this hit `\texttt` in particular and not `\textsf`

Comment: @daleif sorry I didn't see your comment until after I had posted. The effect does hit `\textsf` but it is less pronounced there/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the affect of the default `\nonfrenchspacing` which adds extra space after sentence/clause ending punctuation. The monospacing of `\texttt` highlights the effect.

```
\texttt{\frenchspacing1234 : 8901}\\
```

produces even spacing as does

```
\verb|1234 : 8901|\\
```

Comment: Thanks for this — I guess I hadn't hit this before since I usually use verbatim, fancyvrb or the listings environments for code. This is covered on pages 72–74 of the TeXbook

Answer (score 11):

The space after the colon is bigger also in `\textsf`, but much less than in `\texttt`. If I try

```
\sbox0{\textsf{1234 : 8901}}\showthe\wd0
\sbox0{\frenchspacing\textsf{1234 : 8901}}\showthe\wd0
```

I get

```
> 59.40216pt.
l.28 \sbox0{\textsf{1234 : 8901}}\showthe\wd0

?
> 58.09662pt.
l.29 ...chspacing\textsf{1234 : 8901}}\showthe\wd0
```

so an extra 1.3pt is added without frenchspacing. The abnormal spacing in `\texttt` is due to the font spacing parameters; these are those for `cmtt10`

```
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.524996)
   (STRETCH R 0.0)
   (SHRINK R 0.0)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.430555)
   (QUAD R 1.049991)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.524996)
   )
```

while `cmss10` has

```
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.333334)
   (STRETCH R 0.166667)
   (SHRINK R 0.111112)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.444445)
   (QUAD R 1.000003)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.111112)
   )
```

and `EXTRASPACE` is the culprit here, together with the space factor code associated to the colon, which is 2000.

Now, `\ttfamily` can be used for emulating a typewriter and space factor works like typists were used to do (at least in the US), leaving additional space after sentence ending periods and colons.

You can redefine `\ttfamily` to be "non space extending" by adding the following code to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\let\ttfamily\relax % avoid a spurious warning
\DeclareRobustCommand\ttfamily
        {\not@math@alphabet\ttfamily\mathtt
         \fontfamily\ttdefault\selectfont\frenchspacing}
\makeatother
```

The command `\texttt` uses internally the current definition of `\ttfamily`, so you don't need to redefine it.

This is simply the kernel definition of `\ttfamily`, with `\frenchspacing` added. More simply,

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\frenchspacing}{}{}
```

#### Update 2022

Newer releases of LaTeX provide hooks and the task can be accomplished more easily.

```
\documentclass{article}

\AddToHook{cmd/ttfamily/after}{\frenchspacing}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Look ma: no extra space!}

\texttt{\nonfrenchspacing Look ma: extra space!} % for comparison

\end{document}
```

In the second example, `\nonfrenchspacing` undoes the effect of `\frenchspacing`.

[image]

Comment: Nowadays, `\AddToHook{cmd/ttfamily/after}{\frenchspacing}` does the same with no extra package.

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS Indeed!