# How to write "@(x)x.^2" in latex?

Tags: symbols, texmaker, characters

I tried `\texttt{@(x)x.^2}` or directly `@(x)x.^2` but texmaker gives `Missing $ inserted`. I gues it is because `x.^2` which is assumed to be math syntax. Can you help?

Comment: `\verb|@(x)x.^2|`

Comment: @Jake Probably there is a duplicate, but the one you've indicated doesn't seem to be the right one.

Comment: @karlkoeller: I think it is the right one, it's concerned with printing special characters, and egreg's answer suggests using `\verb`. But feel free to suggest a different question, whichever gets used most in the close votes will be displayed as the duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate: [When should one use \verb and when \texttt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2790/579)