# Using \[ \] in text

Tags: math-mode

I am currently writing out an introduction to LaTeX file for some coworkers. How would I insert `\[` `\]` as regular text and not starting math mode?

FYI: The reason why I'm asking this is because I plan on surrounding them with `\texttt`.

Comment: Read about verbatim.

Comment: I need it to be inline, so `verbatim` will not work.

Comment: So read about `\verb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention "inline", I will point out that `\verb` will not break across lines.  However, if that is needed, then this approach, using `\detokenize` could work **if** you don't have unbalanced braces, and if you don't need to print `%` or `#` signs in the string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\detokenize{\[ This is a test this is a test this is a test
This is a test this is a test this is a test \]}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`fontenc` is not needed in this example, but would be if you wanted to print out the result in anything other than `\texttt`.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out thanks to the comment by Sigur.

`\verb#\[# \verb#\]#`

or alternatively, thanks to Sigur as well,

`\verb+\[ \]+`.

I read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/when-should-one-use-verb-and-when-texttt) previously, which seemed to suggest to me that I *always* needed to use `texttt`, but it looks like I was wrong.

Comment: You don't need to use it twice: `verb+\[ \]+` also works.

Comment: Use `\verb` when the content has some special chars (for example, braces, dollar signs, etc...