# Force latex to parse command as raw text

Tags: code, typewriter

I'm writing a text about programming and want to include some inline small code snippets. In markdown one would simply use backticks for this `test`. This automatically becomes monospace font. I want a simple command for this. (Backticks would even be better)

I tried using:

```
\newcommand{\mon}[1]{
    \mbox{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
}
```

My command is `\mon` with one parameter, the \texttt is for the monospace and detokenize is for characters which would otherwise be parsed by Latex.(Like $, & etc) However this doesn't work for `#`. If I want to use `\mon{F#}` I get this error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. \mon{F#}
```

Here is a test document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mon}[1]{
    \mbox{\texttt{\protect\detokenize{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}
    \mon{F#}
\end{document}
```

I also tried with using a custom environment. I guess it must be possible since `lstlistings` is doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're probably looking for `\verb|F#|`

Comment: @egreg thanks. I read about \verb what I also read it has some disadvantages. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2791/91093

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all information in the answers and other questions on tex, I finally found a 100% working solution for my situation. I was probably not clear enough in my question.

What I want is:

- use `\mon` everywhere I want, inside tables and items, but also in other commands. (Which doesn't work for verbatim)
- use monospace
- maybe use a gray background

Some users reported it here that I should use `lstinline` which turned out to be the solution. I'm using this code in my class:

```
\newenvironment{stable}{
    \begin{longtable}{ p{6cm}  p{10cm} }
}{
    \\
\end{longtable}
}
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\tt
}

\newcommand{\mon}[1]{%
    \colorbox{lightgray!30}{\lstinline{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\sitem}[1]{%
    \\ { \bfseries #1} &    
}
```

And know I can create a "two column page" like this in my document:

```
\begin{stable}      
    \sitem{Use \mon{const string*}} lorem ipsum \mon{string}
\end{stable}
```

With this as result:

[image: result]

Comment: I am not sure if a 100% working solution can contain `\\ \\ \bf{#1} &`, which is asking for trouble.

Comment: I understand that it isn't beautiful latex and it's an hack. It's just to easily type `\sitem` instead of copy pasting the same commands over and over again.

Comment: The code will fail in normal text. You cannot have a double line break, `\bf` is deprecated for 20 years and you cannot have an ampersand in normal text. It seems you are using this within a table, but this might be a clue that something else isn't designed right.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The double line break was a typo. I replaced the `\bf` by `\bfseries`. My intention of these macro's is to easily use the same layout in all my documents. So when I want may first column to be bigger, I only have to change it in the global class. The left column is basically a description for the right column.

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly do it with `\verb`. But let's look what happens with your attempt. In

```
\newcommand{\mon}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    \texttt{%
      \protect\detokenize{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

there is a misplaced `\protect` that however does nothing bad. The problem is that TeX sees `#`<sub>6</sub> before the “detokenization” actually takes place and this results in a bad token list to be passed as argument to `\texttt`. Indeed, if you use `\ttfamily` the problem is solved:

```
\newcommand{\mon}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    \ttfamily
    \detokenize{#1}%
  }%
}
```

A different strategy could be performing `\detokenize` before doing anything else:

```
\newcommand{\mon}[1]{%
   \expandafter\monAUX\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\monAUX}[1]{%
  \mbox{\texttt{#1}}%
}
```

This however ***doesn't*** solve the problem with `F#`, because you'll clearly see the `#` is doubled. That's part of how `\detokenize` works (and TeX is designed), so for this particular application I'm afraid `\verb` is the solution. Or some less heavy trick that changes the category code of `#` (so it can't be used in the argument to another command).

---

A different approach might be with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nx \c_ledfan_doublehash_tl { \tl_to_str:n { # } }
\tl_new:N \l_ledfan_mon_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\mon}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nf \l_ledfan_mon_tl { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:NVV \l_ledfan_mon_tl \c_ledfan_doublehash_tl \c_hash_str
  \texttt{ \tl_use:N \l_ledfan_mon_tl }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { NVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mon{F#}

\mon{C##}

\end{document}
```

The assumption is that any `##` in the token list we build comes from `\tl_to_str:n` (which is `\detokenize` in disguise) applied to a `#`<sub>6</sub> token, so it's replaced by a single one.

[image]

This has still some limitations, because it can't go in the argument of any argument that performs some `\protected@edef` or `\protected@write`; for instance `\textbf` and similar commands or `\section`, `\caption` and friends.

Comment: Your second code snippet does everything I want. (Even in descriptions) Why does everybody use % at the end of their line?

Comment: @LEDfan That's for avoiding spurious spaces. I added a final comment: `\mon{F#}` will produce the wrong result with `\detokenize`.

Comment: Oh, I just saw the ##, I got that problem too.