# what is the differences between "\verb" and "\tt"

Tags: fonts, verbatim, typewriter

I am wondering the diffference between `\verb` and `\tt`.

For example

`\verb|difference|` appears the same with `\tt{difference}`

Comment: Try it with `$%#\\^` as the argument.

Comment: Related to [When should one use \verb and when \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2790)

Answer (score 29):

The difference is that `\verb` is an inline verbatim environment so that everything inside it is taken literally, even what would otherwise be considered a command.  This also happens to use a monospace font because it is usually used to insert code snippets (so that special characters don't pose any issue).

On the other hand, `\tt` (and you really should be using `\texttt{...}`) simply switches the font to monospace font, but LaTeX commands remain as usual.

To illustrate the difference, consider these two:

```
\verb|\emph{hello} world|

\texttt{\emph{hello} world}
```

which produces:

[image: output]

---

As a last remark, you shouldn't use `\tt` and other related commands such as `\bf` and `\it` because they are clumsy to use and don't play well together.  This is [demonstrated well here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text).  To take their place, we have two sets of commands: `\bfseries`, `\ttfamily`; and `\textbf{...}`, `\texttt{...}`.

Comment: It would be probably useful for the OP to see the difference between `\emph{\tt hello}` and `\emph{\texttt{hello}}`. Only the second one produces emphasized typewriter style, the first only produces typewriter style without emphasis.

Comment: @guanglei: … and in any case, even in the old days it was `{\tt hello}` and *not* `\tt{hello}`.  With the latter syntax the effects of `\tt` are *not* limited to the word `hello`.