# How to write the same hash mark # symbol as the one on the texbook?

Tags: symbols

In the texbook, the `hash mark` symbol is obtained with the sequence `\#` which produces this.

[image: hash mark]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\#
\end{document}
```

But on the texbook itself, there is the hash mark preceded by the backslash `\`which does not have the same form as the one obtained.

[image: hash mark]

How to get the `texbook` symbol here underlined in yellow?

Comment: Could that just be `\texttt{\#}`?

Comment: yes it is, please write an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the typewriter/`tt` version of the symbol.

I guess the TeXbook uses some kind of verbatim mode to typeset the example from the question

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\#}

\verb|\#| gives \#
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, please add a screenshot

Comment: @AndréC Unfortunately, my internet connection is a bit flaky at the moment and won't allow me to upload pictures. Feel free to add a screenshot.

Comment: I added an image.

Comment: @daleif Thanks.

Comment: I have just noticed the use of the macro `\verb`, can you give some details about this macro? What is it used for, its use, its origin, etc? I have personally researched this, and I know the answers, but this will save other readers from doing the same.

Comment: @AndréC Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2790/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303865/35864 and §53.3 Verbatim (File y: `ltmiscen.dtx`) of [`source2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf). I'd guess that every more advanced LaTeX introduction would  cover verbatim text and in particular the `verbatim` environment and `\verb`.

Comment: I have already read these pages, I ask you to add some explanations so that the users reading your answer are not forced to do this research which takes time and which we often miss. :-)