# First tag of nested description environment with newline style wont appear on new line

Tags: line-breaking, enumitem, description

I have the next document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setdescription{style=nextline, font=\mdseries, align=left}
\setdescription[2]{style=nextline, font=\mdseries, align=left}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\tt #1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{description}
    \item[\code{int} (value type)]
        \begin{description}
            \item[\code{int = a}]
                Значення не змінюється.
            \item[\code{ref int = a}]
                Значення змінюється.
            \item[\code{int = new int; int = a}]
                Значення не змінюється.
            \item[\code{ref int = new int; int = a}]
                Значення змінюється.
        \end{description}
    \item[\code{struct} (value type)]
        \begin{description}
            \item[\code{struct = a}]
                Значення не змінюється.
            \item[\code{ref struct = a}]
                Значення змінюється.
            \item[\code{struct = new struct; struct = a}]
                Значення не змінюється.
            \item[\code{ref struct = new struct; struct = a}]
                Значення змінюється.
        \end{description}
        Так як \code{struct} це тип-значення то поведінка аналогічна до типу \code{int}.
    \item[\code{int[]} (reference type)]
        \begin{description}
            \item[\code{int[] = a}]
                Значення змінюється.
            \item[\code{ref int[] = a}]
                Значення змінюється.
            \item[\code{int[] = new int[]; int[] = a}]
                Значення змінюється.
            \item[\code{ref int[] = new int[]; int[] = a}]
                Значення змінюється.
        \end{description}
    \item[\code{string} (reference type)]
        \begin{description}
            \item[\code{int[] = a}]
                Значення не змінюється.
            \item[\code{ref int[] = a}]
                Значення змінюється.
            \item[\code{int[] = new int[]; int[] = a}]
                Значення не змінюється.
            \item[\code{ref int[] = new int[]; int[] = a}]
                Значення змінюється.
        \end{description}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

It produces almost what I want:

[image]

But notice the first nested description: the `\item[\code{int = a}]` must go to new line but it follows the `\item[\code{int} (value type)]` for some reason. How to make it appear on new line? I tried to find something about it in enumitem docs but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- `\setdescription` is deprecated, replaced by `\setlist[description,<levels>]{<format>}`
- defined command `\directenv`, that can be used, if there is no text following, but directly another environment:

  ```
  \newcommand{\directenv}{\hfill\vspace{-1.7\baselineskip}}
  ```
- reduced the example code and added an item with text (for comparison)
- replaced the old tex command `\tt #1` by latex command `\texttt{#1}` (or `\ttfamily #1`)

#### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline, font=\mdseries, align=left}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\directenv}{\hfill\vspace{-1.7\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[\code{int} (value type)]\directenv
    \begin{description}
        \item[environment item]
            foo
    \end{description}
\item[\code{struct} (value type)]
    direct text (no environment)
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: The solution and correction are amazing! I would like to know, how I can reduce the vertical space after the  `\item[\code{int} (value type)]\mbox{}`? I mean, I could just do `\vspace{-8mm}` after each `\mbox{}`, but maybe you know the approach that would fit better.

Comment: @VladyslavRehan I made an edit to my answer.

Comment: `\ttfamily`, not `\ttshape`

Comment: @egreg oh, I took the error from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303867/123129) without checking it. I have corrected it here. You may comment there as well ;)

Comment: @dexteritas Thank You! Answer accepted!