# same size letters

Tags: fonts, formatting, letters

I need to write a text where the letters are aligned with each other, I mean something like this :

[image]

however since usually not all letters occupy the same space, I get this:

[image]

is there some font where all uppercase letters have the same size? or is there maybe another way to do this?

Comment: Sure: [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). Try `\texttt{}` for the Computer Modern one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Au101 already mentionend, `texttt{your text}` is your way to go. Actually it produces output similar to `this one`, so every letter has the same width.

You can use it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{your text - IN CAPITALS}

{\ttfamily yourtext no. 2}
\end{document}
```

An alternative would be `{\ttfamily yourtext}`

Depending on your use, this might be helpful: [When should one use \verb and when \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/when-should-one-use-verb-and-when-texttt)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `stretch` optional argument to `\makebox` (or `\framebox`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\mybox}[2][5cm]{%
  % \framebox
  \makebox[#1][s]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\mybox[3cm]{M I C H I G A N} \hfill \mybox{T E C H N O L O G I C A L} \hfill \mybox[4cm]{U N I V E R S I T Y}

\mybox[3cm]{H O U G T O N} \hfill \mybox{H O U G H T O N H O U G H} \hfill \mybox[4cm]{T O N H O U G H N T O}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the 'other' way for when a monospaced font is inappropriate.

Comment: That took a bit more space than I intended but it worked too, thanks