# Inline verbatim

Tags: verbatim, html, inline

I would like to write something like this inline:

> This is paragraph element `<p>`

I'm using `verbatim` for writing the HTML element part, but cannot form everything in one line. I get something like this:

> This is paragraph element
>   `<p>`

After looking through some answers on this forum I found that I should use `\verb`.
Can anyone help me correct my code:

```
This is paragraph element
\begin{verbatim}
<p>
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What is wrong with `\verb!<p>!`? There are also some packages that provide inline display for various programming languages , see `listings` or `minted`, for example

Comment: Did you try "`This is paragraph element \verb+<p>+.`"? Note the use of the delimiter `+` to start and terminate the inline verbatim material. The delimiter can be any symbol that doesn't occur in the verbatim material.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer this works perfectly for me. I thought that using `verbatim` was the only way I could achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: this should provide additional useful information: [When should one use \verb and when \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2790)

Answer (score 32):

To typeset inline verbatim-like material, it's best to use the macros `\verb` and `\Verb`; the latter is provided by the `fancyvrb` package. If that package is loaded and the instruction `\VerbatimFootnotes` is executed, one can even have `\Verb` instructions in footnotes. (One can't do this with `\verb`.)

Note that `\verb` and `\Verb` don't use matching pairs of curly braces (`{` and `}`) to delimit their arguments; instead, use any non-letter symbol (*except* "`*`") that doesn't occur in the verbatim material itself. (Even `\verb{<p>{` is legal, though I'll be the first one to state that it looks positively weird.)

If you prefer to render the inline verbatim material using the "regular" text font instead of a monospaced font, consider loading the `listings` package and writing "`Paragraph element \lstinline{<p>}`".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} % for "\Verb" macro
\VerbatimFootnotes    % enable use of \Verb in footnotes

\setlength\textheight{3cm} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\obeylines
Paragraph element \verb+<p>+
Paragraph element \verb_</p>_
Paragraph element \Verb^<p>^
Paragraph element \Verb#</p>#
\VerbatimFootnotes
Some text.\footnote{In a footnote: \Verb"<p>",  \Verb:</p>:.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "use any non-letter symbol": this was true before 2020/04/22, but now it should be replaced by "use any non-space symbol (it should be letter after space)". The change in LaTeX2e kernel was done by  https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/4f02ccd61d70534f80a96bf3fa1d304a996ac0ce#diff-311522c46cf73477c4cc418ef0908db3e36af092d34b7a2fbdc36d38e94805cc see lines 1162--1171.

Comment: @wipet - Many thanks for noticing and pointing out this significant change. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @wipet - Sorry for this long delay in getting back to you. I just checked, and `\verb*<p>*` still isn't valid syntax. I would appear that your claim, that "any non-space symbol" should be a permissible delimiter, isn't quite right. Or did I maybe miss something?

Answer (score 4):

Code golfing with `xparse` and its `v` - argument specifier, meaning `verbatim` or just use `\verb!<p>!` for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ShowInline}{v}{%
#1%
}

\begin{document}
Some HTML \ShowInline{<p>}

End tag for HTML\ShowInline{</p>}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some advantage to using this approach to, say, loading the `listings` package and typing `Some HTML \lstinline{<p>}`?

Comment: @Mico: None, actually. That's why I called it code golfing ;-)