# LaTeX method for outputting raw text

Tags: text, text-manipulation

Is there a method in LaTeX typing that would enable to output the exact text between a statement of beginning and statement of end of such a method, including special characters and new lines?

Something like `<pre></pre>` in HTML.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. // Look for verbatim.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387684/125871) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247404/125871) help?