# LaTeX Nesting \verb in \section

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, nesting, parsing, arguments

Why is

```
\section{\verb|mySec|}
```

invalid LaTeX code.

Comment: Not valid: `\begin{array}{cc} \textit{a & b} \end{array}`. In general, scoping cannot cross another group.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because verbatim content always causes you trouble.

The `\section` command takes one argument, which in the first case, is `\textit{mySec}` and in the second it is `\verb|mySec|`.

Everything by now was read and tokenized by TeX with the due category codes. In the first case you have a control sequence `\textit`, a open brace with `\catcode` 1, 5 characters with `\catcode` 11, and a close brace with `\catcode` 2. So far so good.

The same goes for the second case, but this time you have a control sequence `\verb` and 7(!) characters with `\catcode` 11 (the `|` is `\catcode` 12, but that doesn't do much here).

The problem here is that the `|` are already tokenized by TeX, so their catcode can't change. But the first(ish) thing that `\verb` does is to make the `\catcode` of the `|` active, but it can't anymore, thus you get an error.

Basically, verbatim content can't appear as arguments to a macro, unless that macro is carefully built to allow it.

---

If you're interested in a workaround, though, you could use Bruno Le Floch's `cprotect`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}
\section{\textit{mySec}}
\cprotect\section{\verb|mySec|}
\end{document}
```