# Cannot do \paragraph{\verb}

Tags: paragraphs, verbatim

Is there any way to put `\verb` inside `\paragraph` or an alternative way to simulate this?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! `\verb` cannot be used in macro arguments. The package `fancyvrb` offers some workarounds, but usually a simple `\texttt` (possibly with some escaping) is enough. ([related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24574/48973) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33113/48973))

Comment: Hi, see https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin

Comment: See also [LaTeX Nesting \verb in \section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447076/5001)

Comment: Thanks those who answered. `\texttt` worked.